# Why do DisplayName() and Label() Html helpers lose the left part of the decimal value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a value of 12345678.1200 in the database which is of decimal type. I also bind it as decimal on the view. (so item.Value from the code below is decimal)

These lines of code:

```
@item.Value
@item.Value.ToString("##,#.##")
@Html.Label(item.Value.ToString())
@Html.DisplayName(item.Value.ToString())
@Html.Label(item.Value.ToString("##,#.##"))
@Html.DisplayName(item.Value.ToString("##,#.##"))
```

tender the following values in the view:

```
12345678.1200   
12,346,678.12   
1200    
1200    
12  
12
```

You see I tried formatting the value but it didn't help. What is going on here, and can I make the Label() / DisplayName() helpers to render proper values? Label() and DisplayName() also don't accept the decimal type so I had to use ToString().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should decorate your view model property with the `[DisplayFormat]` helper if you want to pass some format:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:##,#.##}")]
public decimal MyViewModelProperty { get; set; }
```

Now when you use the Display (or the more recommended DisplayFor) helper the specified format will be used:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.MyViewModelProperty)
```

As far as the Html.Label helper is concerned, you could use the second argument to specify the format:

```
@Html.Label("MyViewModelProperty", MyViewModelProperty.ToString("##,#.##"))
```